# In the context of writing a parser based on the LR(0) algorithm what are magic and tau steps?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lr-grammar

A task that I have to do specifies:

> Start by defining the non-deterministic machine which performs shift-reduce stages with the help of magic or tau steps

However, I can't find any references to what a magic or tau step is in Compilers: Principles, Techniques & Tools (Aho et. al) or by searching on the internet.

Please could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I think they just mean that you should assume the actual shift-reduce step is a black box, and just define everything around it. Tau is a form of black magic according to Google.